# How to select multiple checkbox from single column data in c# .net

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, checkbox

I am trying to make a restaurant form which stores data to a database when a user orders food. If the user comes again and enters his first and last name, the other data, like food and pickup option, should be filed automatically. For the food, I have a checkbox.

Here is the insert code:

```
string strCheckValue = "";
if (CheckBox1.Checked)
{
    strCheckValue = strCheckValue + "," + CheckBox1.Text;
}
if (CheckBox2.Checked)
{
    strCheckValue = strCheckValue + "," + CheckBox2.Text;
}
if (CheckBox3.Checked)
{
    strCheckValue = strCheckValue + "," + CheckBox3.Text;
}
if (CheckBox4.Checked)
{
    strCheckValue = strCheckValue + "," + CheckBox4.Text;
}
if (CheckBox5.Checked)
{
    strCheckValue = strCheckValue + "," + CheckBox5.Text;
}
if (CheckBox6.Checked)
{
    strCheckValue = strCheckValue + "," + CheckBox6.Text;
}
if (CheckBox7.Checked)
{
    strCheckValue = strCheckValue + "," + CheckBox7.Text;
}
```

The strCheckValue is stored in the database and gives result like this:
**,Samosa,Biryani,Naan**

Now I want to select all the food items a user previously selected while ordering the food when he hits remember me button.

For that my code is:

```
//checkbox value display
CheckBox1.Checked = false;
CheckBox2.Checked = false;
CheckBox3.Checked = false;
CheckBox4.Checked = false;
CheckBox5.Checked = false;
CheckBox6.Checked = false;
CheckBox7.Checked = false;
string aa = dr["ctm_food"].ToString();
string[] a = aa.Split(',');
Label10.Text = a[2].ToString();
foreach (Control cc in this.Controls)
{
    if(cc is CheckBox)
    {
        CheckBox b = (CheckBox)cc;
        for(int j=1; j<a.Length; j++)
        {
            if (a[j].ToString() == b.Text)
            {
                b.Checked = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In label10, I can see the food that the user ordered. But the checkbox is not getting selected. What will be the right approach to complete this exercise?

Comment: Which ASP.NET are you using?

Comment: Which code is executed when? When you want to remember the user's choices? What issue you are facing with this code?

Comment: it is 4.0 @JohnKennedy

Comment: The insert code is used when user hits order button. That is the code to remember user's choices. But when user presses remember me button, I can retrieve all the data but not able to check checkbox according to the data. @ChetanRanpariya

Comment: Maybe you need `b.Text.ToString()` for text comparison instead of reference comparison? Besides, create an array of checkboxes and iterate through it. It will make the code more enjoyable.

Comment: Did you debug the code and see if code is executing properly? If it is not then tell us which line is not executing or any error you are getting.

Comment: I tried but it is still not working. @Gedrox

Comment: Debugging is not giving any error @ChetanRanpariya

Comment: Debugging not only for error. You should check what values are being populated in variables and if the code works as expected and where is it behaving different then expected

Comment: Is this ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe `this.Controls` does not contain your checkboxes. It will also simplify your code if you'd keep all checkbox references in one place.

```
CheckBox[] checkboxes = new CheckBox[] {
    CheckBox1, CheckBox2, CheckBox3, CheckBox4, CheckBox5, CheckBox6, CheckBox7
};

string aa = dr["ctm_food"].ToString();
string[] a = aa.Split(',');
Label10.Text = a[2].ToString();

foreach (CheckBox b in checkboxes) {
    b.Checked = false;
    for (int j = 1; j < a.Length; j++) {
        if (a[j].ToString() == b.Text) {
            b.Checked = true;
        }
    }
}
```